# Rails: query postgres jsonb using where error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a jsonb column in my postgres `performances` table called `authorization` where I store the uuid of a user as a key and their authorization level as the value e.g.

```
{ 'sf4wfw4fw4fwf4f': 'owner', 'ujdtud5vd9': 'editor' }
```

I use the below Rails query in my `Performance` model to search for all records where the user is an owner:

```
class Performance < ApplicationRecord

      def self.performing_or_owned_by(account)
        left_outer_joins(:artists)
          .where(artists: { id: account } )
          .or(Performance.left_outer_joins(:artists)
            # this is where the error happens
            .where("authorization @> ?", { account => "owner" }.to_json)
          ).order('lower(duration) DESC')
           .uniq
      end

end
```

Where `account` is the account uuid of the user. However, when I run the query I get the following error:

```
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@>")
    LINE 1: ..._id" WHERE ("artists"."id" = $1 OR (authorization @> '{"28b5...
```

The generated SQL is:

```
SELECT "performances".* FROM "performances" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "artist_performances" ON "artist_performances"."performance_id" = "performances"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "artists" ON "artists"."id" = "artist_performances"."artist_id" WHERE ("artists"."id" = $1 OR (authorization @> '{"28b5fc7f-3a31-473e-93d4-b36f3b913269":"owner"}')) 
ORDER BY lower(duration) DESC
```

I tried several things but keep getting the same error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In what model did you use this code? Which table has `authorization` column?

Comment: in the `performance` model / table, which has the `authorization `column. I will add that to the question.

Comment: Would wrapping authorization in quotes fix the issue?

Comment: Did you try this: `left_outer_joins(:artists).where(artists: { id: account } ).or(left_outer_joins(:artists).where("authorization ->> ? = 'owner'", account))`

Comment: @crtag you found it. I had to wrap `authorization` in quotes and it has to be double quotes. Single quote would still throw an error. If you want, post an answer: `.where('"authorization" @> ?', { account => "owner" }.to_json)` and I will give you the check.

Comment: @Darkisa cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as per comment in the original question is to wrap the `authorization` in double-quotes. Eg:

```
.where('"authorization" @> ?', { account => "owner" }.to_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `->>` operator gets a JSON object field as text.

So it looks you need this query:

```
left_outer_joins(:artists).
  where("artists.id = ? OR authorization ->> ? = 'owner'", account, account).
  order('lower(duration) DESC').
  uniq
```

Comment: Even with the ->> operator I still get the same error. My best guess is with something with how I am using quotations